# ImageMagick convert jpg images to gif slow

Tags: imagemagick, png, jpeg, gif

I am using Magick++(IM 7.0.3 platform:CentOS Linux release 7.0) to convert images to gif. I create Image objects from files, the problem is that when I convert 9 png files(each 50kb) to gif, it taks only 50ms. but when it turns to 9 jpg files (each 20kb), it takes 1900ms. What is the reason behind? How can I make it faster with jpg files?

```
 for(int i = 2; i < argc-1; i++)
  {
    // I pass the file path from command line
    cout << argv[i] << endl;
    Image img(argv[i]);
    img.animationDelay(delay);
    img.magick("GIF");
    frames.push_back(img);
  }
  long mergestart = getCurrentTime();
  Magick::Blob tmpBlob;
  Magick::writeImages(frames.begin(), frames.end(), &tmpBlob);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would guess that the PNG files are either palettised or contain relatively few colours, whereas the JPEGs will have thousands of colours, so **ImageMagick** will be forced to do a lot more work to reduce and optimise the colours for the relatively small palette of 256 colours a GIF can contain.

Check my theory on your files by running:

```
identify -verbose Any.PNG
```

and

```
identify -verbose Any.JPG
```

and look at the `Number of colours`.

Alternatively, you can use this command to count the colours:

```
identify -format %k AnyImage.png
```

If you want to make it faster because you have thousands of files to process, you could use multi-threading, or something like **GNU Parallel** to get more done at once.

Comment: thanks for help. I don't have this "identify" IM command, but with php GD Library imagecolorstotal function, I got my jpg color number 0 and png color number 256. does that mean png files are palettised ?

Comment: sorry but  I have another question: I tried to construct a png formatted Magick::Image obj, but failed to init the Image with blob(blob is constructed by png data which is created by  cv::imencode); but init with a cv::imencode jpg blob works fine. I am new to image processing, and got stuck here.

Comment: Questions are free - put the **OpenCV** issue in a new, separate question and tag it accordingly for best help.

Comment: Thanks to your help. :-) I got identify tool and ran this "identify -format %k AnyImage.png". The png color num is 256  while the jpg color num is 21627.  Is it possible to re-format the jpg data to make it less color num or do something else to help with the converting speed.

Comment: There is not much you can do if your data is JPEG - that's just the way it is. What sort of images are they - graphics, cartoons, animations, photographs?  What are you actually trying to do **overall** such that 1850ms is so critical?

Comment: I am building a web application, where user upload a selfie to get a face-merged gif as return. The 2s time cost is unbearable for me.  I do these processes in server: I merge the selfie face to several model pictures, the merged pictures will be convert from cv::mat to jpg/png(using cv::imencode). Then I will create Magick::Image objs with these jpg/png rawdata, the problem occurs when I try to write Images To gif. So the problem here is graphic compression time cosuming? I found ffmpeg command line to generate gif works quickly, but using its api might be a lot to do for me. Any advice pls?

Comment: Not sure what to suggest. One idea might be to take a sample of a few hundred selfies and reduce the number of colours to 250 or so and generate a fixed, constant palette then try *remapping* all incoming selfies to that before merging - I'm basically guessing that remapping might be faster than reducing. Maybe someone clever will know... @emcconville ?

Comment: I think this approach is wrong. You want to pass the _image_ data from `cv::Mat` to `Magick::Image`, not the image _format_ data. The former being a quick memory copy, and the latter involving duplicated/unneeded encoding & compression. I'll post a solution in the other question, but please accept Mark's fantastic answer as it does address the performance question here.

Comment: @emcconville D'oh! I managed to miss the fact that OP was encoding and decoding every frame between OpenCV and IM - despite the fact that he stated it clearly. D'oh, d'oh, d'oh!

Comment: Thanks for your kind help and suggestion. I am trying to do some quantization(with pngquant) to the png data  before involve in ImageMagick.

Comment: using the cv::Mat data to init Magick::Image, then write the image_frames to blob or gif file is faster than init Image with jpeg raw data. But the result gif seems too large. How can I make each frame be lower quality? img.compressType(JPEGCompression);
img.quality(60);   these codes I tried didn't work for this.

Comment: Wthout seeing your actual code and images, I can only suggest you quantize the number of colours down across the entire sequence to ensure the palette is both small and identical across all frames and that will make the animation smaller as **ImageMagick** won't have to include multiple, slightly different palettes. Try grossly quantising down to 30 colours, to see if it helps then go up to 60 colours or so to see if it is good enough.

Comment: I also suspect it might be better **not** to call `image.magick("GIF")` on each individual frame as that may be prematurely reducing the colours of each induvidual frame - but to a different set of colours for each frame rather than a common set across all frames. I may be wrong - I have not tested.

Comment: I luckily called image.magick("GIF") only for the first frame. And I did the color reduction for each cv::Mat separately, it maked sense. I will try the "identical across all frames" thing later. Now with the 200x200 cv::Mat, animating 8 frames takes 120ms which is acceptable for me. According to your suggestion, a gif don't need so many different palletes, I guess I can try to reduce the face-merge-timecost with this idea. Thanks Mark && emc.