# how to init a Magick::Image obj with blob constructed by png data(png was create by cv::imencode)

Tags: c++, opencv, imagemagick

I tried to create a Magick::Image obj with blob constructed by png data(png was create by cv::imencode). It works fine when I create a Magick::Image obj with blob constructed by jpg data(jpg was create by cv::imencode), but I cannot do it with png data.

I want to convert some imgs to gif. The source data are img rawdatas encoded by cv::imencode. I can work out with jpg data, but it's too slow, so I tried to do it with png data, now I got the problem mentioned above.

Related Question: [ImageMagick convert jpg images to gif slow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43883998/imagemagick-convert-jpg-images-to-gif-slow/43885010?noredirect=1#comment74805704_43885010)

Comment: Any exceptions thrown, or error messages?

Comment: @emcconville yes, I got a Magick:: Error: Magick: MemoryAllocationFailed `' @ error/png.c/ReadOnePNGImage/2144

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't bother encoding `cv::Mat` to any image format blob, only to pass to `Magick::Image` for decoding. Just pass the pixel data directly to `Magick::Image.read`.

```cpp
cv::Mat inbound_image = cv::imread("wizard.jpg");
Magick::Image outbound_image;
outbound_image.read(inbound_image.cols,  // width
                    inbound_image.rows,  // height
                    "BGR",               // Channel order (should always be "BGR", or "BGRA")
                    Magick::CharPixel,   // CV_8U
                    inbound_image.data); // void *
outbound_image.write("wizard.gif");
```

Please note that you'll be responsible for checking `cv::Mat.depth()` for correct storage size, and `cv::Mat.channels()` to color channel count.

Comment: Thanks. But I somehow have to deal with the encoded data. I found that with the same color numbers of png and jpg,  converting png to gif is faster than converting jpg to gif (is that true?). So I want to pass a png-compressed data to Magick::Image, but I got the problem I posted.

Comment: your hint works. I do Magick::Image.quantizeColors(256) for each frame image. With Image init with jpeg raw data, quantizeColors works slow, but with cv::Mat, quantizeColors works significantly faster.

Comment: Correct. OpenCv has hardware optimization at compile time. ImageMagick has various kernels that can be enabled/configured via OpenCL + OpenMP. Also, ImageMagick 7 defaults to HDRI-16Q, so higher quality/precision, but more data to process. Recompiling IM with hardware accelerators, 8Q, and no HDRI, and you'll find IM matching OpenCV in performance.